# Command line documentation viewer for node js modules

Tags: node.js, command-line, module, documentation

Is there a way to display the documentation of installed NodeJS packages in a **console window** (as a command line tool)? Often - in case of editing on a server - it is easier to view the docs of some specific stuff right in the command window, then to start a browser.

Such as `npm docs fs` or `npm docs express` would be perfect, but these try to start a browser and display documentation there instead of displaying `README.md` directly in the window.

Something similar to Perl's `perldoc` would be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do when I'm in a hurry:

```
# nodedoc
# USAGE: nodedoc <name of module>
# e.g. nodedoc http

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/master/doc/api/$1.md | pandoc --from markdown --to plain | less
```